# carry something (with me)?

Tags: meaning

Sometime I see a sentence like this:

*I always carry my notebook with me.*

So, what's the meaning of "with me"? Is it possible that I carry my notebook with someone else? Is it wrong if I omit it? Or is it different from the sentence above in meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "with me" in "I always carry my notebook with me" is used to emphasize that the notebook is always close to where you are. In contrast, if you said "I always carry my notebook in my backpack," and if your backpack isn't with you, then the notebook isn't *with you.*

You wouldn't say "I always carry my notebook with someone else" because it doesn't make sense that there is someone else who has a relationship with your notebook because you carry it. On the other hand, it would make sense to say "I always hold hands with my wife" because "holding hands" usually means with someone else.

You can omit the "with me," but then the relationship between you and the notebook is less specific.

Comment: Is it possible to use "on me" here?

Comment: Yes, you can use "on me" to express the same meaning as "with me" here. You can also use "on my person" which, in this context, means that what you are carrying is either being worn or carried in or on one's clothing.

Comment: @Zhanlong, you can carry a phone on you because it is small. You couldn't carry a notebook computer on you.

Answer (score 0):

> I always carry my notebook with me.

**With** here just means "at the same place" as me.

More examples:

> I have my notebook with me.

That means I have my notebook close to me at the moment.

> I am with Bob.

That means Bob and I are in the same place.